# Visual Studio Code – Пользовательские сокращения и настройки в emmet

Tags: emmet, visual-studio-code

Перехожу с Atom в VSCode. В атоме были созданы 2 файла: *snippets.json* и *preferences.json*, которые исправно работали в Atom, но не работают в VSCode (пути к папкам одинаковые)

Параметры пользователя VSCode

```
{
  "emmet.extensionsPath": "~/emmet/vscode/"
}
```

Вайл *preferences.json*

```
{
  "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /<%= attr('id', '#') %><%= attr('class', '.') %> -->"
}
```

Файл *snippets.json*

```
{
  "html": {
    "filters": "html, c",

    "abbreviations": {
      "glyph": "span[class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"]",
      "jq": "script[src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js\"]",
      "bcmb" : "ol.breadcrumb>li*3>a[href=\"#\"]{ $ }"
    }
  }  
}
```

В файле пробовал писать так:

*preferences.json*

```
{
    "emmet.preferences": {
        "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /<%= attr('id', '#') %><%= attr('class', '.') %> -->"
    }
}
```

snippets.json

```
{
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
      "filters": "html, c",

      "abbreviations": {
        "glyph": "span[class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"]",
        "jq": "script[src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js\"]",
        "bcmb" : "ol.breadcrumb>li*3>a[href=\"#\"]{ $ }"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

но ничего не помогает. Что еще можно предпринять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emmet в vscode работает немного с багами. Удалось решить проблему следующим способом:

Пользовательский файл настроек (User settings) выглядит так:

```
{
    "emmet.extensionsPath": "~/emmet/vscode/",
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.preferences": {
        "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->"
    },
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "html": {
            "filters": "html, c"
        }
    }
}
```

Файл snippets.json (путь берет из emmet.extensionsPath):

```
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "glyph": "span[class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"]",
      "jq": "script[src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js\"]",
      "bcmb" : "ol.breadcrumb>li*3>a[href=\"#\"]{ $ }"
    }
  }
}
```

По сравнению с атомом, изменился параметр abbreviations на snippets